# Conditional logic not working

Tags: sitecore-forms

We've recently upgraded to Sitecore 9.1, and used to work with WFFM. Now we work with Forms, so I'm reconstructing our forms to this new version.

I have an issue with Conditional Logic though, very frustrating.

I have exactly recreated an [example](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17870/sitecore-9-1-forms-conditional-logic-not-working-as-expected/17884#17884) that I found from this website earlier, credits to Fredric Foo, just to make sure I wasn't losing my mind, but it just doesn't work. No matter how the conditions are set, it doesn't hide sections or fields for me.

Could there be any setting that our developer missed while upgrading that I need to enable/change in order for it work? Or should it work out-of-the-box.

I really hope someone can help me out.

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: can you check if you have any js errors?

Answer (score 3):

We ran into this issue as well.  The script that drives the conditional logic requires that the form has both the `MVCLayout.cshtml` and `MVCOuterLayout.cshtml` layouts.  We were missing the `MVCOuterLayout.cshtml` layout.  Once we added that to the form the conditional logic worked.

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/add-a-form-to-a-webpage.html

Comment: Thank you, James! I'll pass this on to our developer, sounds like this will fix the issue.